# Convert YML object/dict to paths of directories using Ansible/Jinja/Python?

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

For an Ansible role that needs to create multiple folders I want to work with a simple representation of the list of paths to create: an human readable YAML "object".

The following pseudo Ansible code should create (if missing) the following folders:

- /home/some-user/dir1
- /home/some-user/dir1/dir1-subdir1
- /home/some-user/dir1/dir1-subdir2
- /home/some-user/dir1/dir1-subdir2/dir1-subdir2-foo
- /home/some-user/dir2
- /home/some-user/dir2/dir2-subdir2
- /home/some-user/dir3

But I fail to find a way to fully traverse the `directory_tree` variable.

```yaml
---
- name: Create directories
  hosts: all

  vars:
     directory_tree:
       base: /home/some-user
       tree:
         dir1:
           dir1-subdir1: null
           dir1-subdir2: null
             dir1-subdir2-foo: null
         dir2:
           dir2-subdir2: null
         dir3: null

  tasks:
  - name: Ensure folders exists
    ansible.builtin.file:
      path: '{{directory_tree.base }}/{{ item }}'
      state: directory
    loop: '{{ directory_tree.tree | …some magic here… }}'
```

Can this be done using Ansible? Or should I code something in Python for this?

Note: In a more advanced version I would have ownership and permissions (and other things) in the variable (in a special `.` key) and `ansible.builtin.file` would exploit them.

```yaml
  vars:
     directory_tree:
       base: /home/some-user
       tree:
         dir1:
           .:
             user: root
             group: root
             mode: 0755
           dir1-subdir1:
             .:
               user: root
               group: root
           dir1-subdir2:
             .:
               user: root
               group: www-data
               mode: 0750
             dir1-subdir2-foo:
               .:
                 user: root
                 group: root
                 mode: 0700
         dir3:
           .:
             # Delete "dir3" folder
             state: absent
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dictionary (below) is not a valid YAML. `dir1-subdir2` shouldn't be *null*

```yaml
     directory_tree:
       base: /home/some-user
       tree:
         dir1:
           dir1-subdir1: null
           dir1-subdir2: null
             dir1-subdir2-foo: null
         dir2:
           dir2-subdir2: null
         dir3: null
```

It's better to omit the explicit *null* values. An empty dictionary evaluates to *null* anyway

```yaml
    directory_tree:
      base: /home/some-user
      tree:
        dir1:
          subdir1:
          subdir2:
            foo:
        dir2:
          subdir2:
        dir3:
```

---

The solutions below are for the above dictionary only. Extended attributes user, group, mode, ... will break the workflow.

1. Create a list of the directories

```yaml
    directory_list: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for k1,v1 in directory_tree.tree.items() %}
      - {{ k1 }}
      {% if v1 %}
      {% for k2,v2 in v1.items() %}
      - {{ k1 }}/{{ k1 }}-{{ k2 }}
      {% if v2 %}
      {% for k3,v3 in v2.items() %}
      - {{ k1 }}/{{ k1 }}-{{ k2 }}/{{ k1 }}-{{ k2 }}-{{ k3 }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}
```

---

Note: Instead of the conditions you can use [default](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.default)

```yaml
    directory_list: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for k1,v1 in directory_tree.tree.items() %}
      - {{ k1 }}
      {% for k2,v2 in (v1|d({}, true)).items() %}
      - {{ k1 }}/{{ k1 }}-{{ k2 }}
      {% for k3,v3 in (v2|d({}, true)).items() %}
      - {{ k1 }}/{{ k1 }}-{{ k2 }}/{{ k1 }}-{{ k2 }}-{{ k3 }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}
```

---

Use it in the loop

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ directory_tree.base }}/{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ directory_list }}"
```

gives abridged

```yaml
  msg: /home/some-user/dir1
  msg: /home/some-user/dir1/dir1-subdir1
  msg: /home/some-user/dir1/dir1-subdir2
  msg: /home/some-user/dir1/dir1-subdir2/dir1-subdir2-foo
  msg: /home/some-user/dir2
  msg: /home/some-user/dir2/dir2-subdir2
  msg: /home/some-user/dir3
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    directory_tree:
      base: /home/some-user
      tree:
        dir1:
          subdir1:
          subdir2:
            foo:
        dir2:
          subdir2:
        dir3:

    directory_list: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for k1,v1 in directory_tree.tree.items() %}
      - {{ k1 }}
      {% if v1 %}
      {% for k2,v2 in v1.items() %}
      - {{ k1 }}/{{ k1 }}-{{ k2 }}
      {% if v2 %}
      {% for k3,v3 in v2.items() %}
      - {{ k1 }}/{{ k1 }}-{{ k2 }}/{{ k1 }}-{{ k2 }}-{{ k3 }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}
 
  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ directory_tree.base }}/{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ directory_list }}"
```

---

2. Create a list of paths

```yaml
  directory_list: "{{ directory_tree.tree|ansible.utils.to_paths }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  directory_list:
    dir1.subdir1: null
    dir1.subdir2.foo: null
    dir2.subdir2: null
    dir3: null
```

Use it in the loop

```yaml
    - file:
        state: directory
        path: "{{ directory_tree.base }}/{{ item|replace('.', '/') }}"
      loop: "{{ directory_list.keys() }}"
```

Take a look at the tree

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_11 find /tmp/ansible-test | sort
/tmp/ansible-test
/tmp/ansible-test/dir1
/tmp/ansible-test/dir1/subdir1
/tmp/ansible-test/dir1/subdir2
/tmp/ansible-test/dir1/subdir2/foo
/tmp/ansible-test/dir2
/tmp/ansible-test/dir2/subdir2
/tmp/ansible-test/dir3
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    directory_tree:
      base: /tmp/ansible-test
      tree:
        dir1:
          subdir1:
          subdir2:
            foo:
        dir2:
          subdir2:
        dir3:

    directory_list: "{{ directory_tree.tree|ansible.utils.to_paths }}"
 
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: directory_list

    - file:
        state: directory
        path: "{{ directory_tree.base }}/{{ item|replace('.', '/') }}"
      loop: "{{ directory_list.keys() }}"
```

---

**Advanced version**

Create the *paths*

```yaml
  paths: "{{ directory_tree.tree|ansible.utils.to_paths }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  paths:
    dir1['.'].group: root
    dir1['.'].mode: 493
    dir1['.'].user: root
    dir1['dir1-subdir1']['.'].group: root
    dir1['dir1-subdir1']['.'].user: root
    dir1['dir1-subdir2']['.'].group: www-data
    dir1['dir1-subdir2']['.'].mode: 488
    dir1['dir1-subdir2']['.'].user: root
    dir1['dir1-subdir2']['dir1-subdir2-foo']['.'].group: root
    dir1['dir1-subdir2']['dir1-subdir2-foo']['.'].mode: 448
    dir1['dir1-subdir2']['dir1-subdir2-foo']['.'].user: root
    dir3['.'].state: absent
```

Use Jinja and create the list of options

```yaml
  opts: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for k,v in paths.items() %}
    {% set arr=k|splitext %}
    - {dir: "{{ arr.0 }}", opt: { {{ arr.1[1:] }}: {{ v }} }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
  opts:
    - dir: dir1['.']
      opt: {user: root}
    - dir: dir1['.']
      opt: {group: root}
    - dir: dir1['.']
      opt: {mode: 493}
    - dir: dir1['dir1-subdir1']['.']
      opt: {user: root}
    - dir: dir1['dir1-subdir1']['.']
      opt: {group: root}
    - dir: dir1['dir1-subdir2']['.']
      opt: {user: root}
    - dir: dir1['dir1-subdir2']['.']
      opt: {group: www-data}
    - dir: dir1['dir1-subdir2']['.']
      opt: {mode: 488}
    - dir: dir1['dir1-subdir2']['dir1-subdir2-foo']['.']
      opt: {user: root}
    - dir: dir1['dir1-subdir2']['dir1-subdir2-foo']['.']
      opt: {group: root}
    - dir: dir1['dir1-subdir2']['dir1-subdir2-foo']['.']
      opt: {mode: 448}
    - dir: dir3['.']
      opt: {state: absent}
```

Merge the list by *dir* and iterate it

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ opt }}"
      loop: "{{ [opts, []]|community.general.lists_mergeby('dir', recursive=true) }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ opt.path }}"
      vars:
        opt:
          path: "{{ item.dir[:-5] }}"
          user: "{{ item.opt.user|d(omit) }}"
          group: "{{ item.opt.group|d(omit) }}"
          mode: "{{ item.opt.mode|d(omit) }}"
          state: "{{ item.opt.state|d(omit) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [test_01] => (item=dir1) => 
  msg:
    group: root
    mode: '493'
    path: dir1
    user: root
ok: [test_01] => (item=dir1['dir1-subdir1']) => 
  msg:
    group: root
    path: dir1['dir1-subdir1']
    user: root
ok: [test_01] => (item=dir1['dir1-subdir2']) => 
  msg:
    group: www-data
    mode: '488'
    path: dir1['dir1-subdir2']
    user: root
ok: [test_01] => (item=dir1['dir1-subdir2']['dir1-subdir2-foo']) => 
  msg:
    group: root
    mode: '448'
    path: dir1['dir1-subdir2']['dir1-subdir2-foo']
    user: root
ok: [test_01] => (item=dir3) => 
  msg:
    path: dir3
    state: absent
```

---

Examplel of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    directory_tree:
      base: /home/some-user
      tree:
        dir1:
          .:
            user: root
            group: root
            mode: 0755
          dir1-subdir1:
            .:
              user: root
              group: root
          dir1-subdir2:
            .:
              user: root
              group: www-data
              mode: 0750
            dir1-subdir2-foo:
              .:
                user: root
                group: root
                mode: 0700
        dir3:
          .:
            # Delete "dir3" folder
            state: absent

    paths: "{{ directory_tree.tree|ansible.utils.to_paths }}"
    opts: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for k,v in paths.items() %}
      {% set arr=k|splitext %}
      - {dir: "{{ arr.0 }}", opt: { {{ arr.1[1:] }}: {{ v }} }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: paths

    - debug:
        var: opts|to_yaml

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ opt }}"
      loop: "{{ [opts, []]|community.general.lists_mergeby('dir', recursive=true) }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ opt.path }}"
      vars:
        opt:
          path: "{{ item.dir[:-5] }}"
          user: "{{ item.opt.user|d(omit) }}"
          group: "{{ item.opt.group|d(omit) }}"
          mode: "{{ item.opt.mode|d(omit) }}"
          state: "{{ item.opt.state|d(omit) }}"
```

Comment: Thank you, the `ansible.utils.to_paths` filter can handle multiple level without modification of the code (but won't support names with `.`): I'll go with that. Any clue for my "advanced version"? I guess it's not doable in Ansible?

Comment: You're welcome. I added example of the advanced version. I left the path concatenation up to you.